# calling stored procedure from MySQL in Cakephp gets only first row of result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

As I call my SP, it only gives me the first result, and on the second call, it gives me this:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

Well, I have checked the related questions as suggested by Stackoverflow. Some gave me the idea but when I tried it, it does not work.

Here's the loop inside my function that calls my SP:

```
foreach ($filenames as $value)
    {
    $queryssid = "CALL GetUniqueSSIDByCategoryCombine('$username','$value');";
    $dataUniqueSSID = $this->User->query($queryssid);
    pr($dataUniqueSSID);
    }
```

here's my SP:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetUniqueSSIDByCategoryCombine`(uid VARCHAR(50),filename VARCHAR(50))
 BEGIN
 SELECT  DISTINCT(transaction_details.essid) AS 'SSID', transaction_details.protocol AS 'protocol', TRANSACTION.filename
 FROM    transaction_details transaction_details, TRANSACTION TRANSACTION  
 WHERE transaction_details.uid_filename_link = TRANSACTION.uid_filename_link AND transaction_details.uid_filename_link = 
     (
         SELECT distinct(transaction.uid_filename_link) FROM TRANSACTION 
         WHERE transaction.uid = uid AND transaction.filename = filename
     ) 
 ORDER BY row_id;
     END
```

What could possibly be the solution. It's my second day dealing with this error and it's kinda frustrating. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, it's my PHP version that is the culprit. From PHP 5.3.1, I upgraded to the latest version.